# Expected Loop error on VBScript for adding users into AD via csv

Tags: windows, vbscript, ldap

I need to add a bunch of users to an AD domain and obviously don't want to manually enter.  I also don't want to use CSVDE because I want to add passwords in.  I don't have much of a background with writing VBScripts so i found one on the internet from techrepublic.  The problem is when I run the script I get an expected loop error and the users in the csv file never get added.  if I throw a loop line at the end of the vbs file it creates the user but then gives me an error that the account already exists, because it is clearly trying to run the script again.
So does anyone have any insight on what I need to change to make this script run properly?

```
' ---------------------------------------------------
' Script: createusersfromcsv.vbs
' Author: Scott Lowe
' Input: CSV file with layout logonname,firstname,lastname,password
' Date: December 21, 2005
' Change log:
' no changes
'----------------------------------------------------

Option Explicit

Dim sCSVFileLocation
Dim sCSVFile
Dim oConnection
Dim oRecordSet
Dim oNewUser

' Variables needed for LDAP connection
Dim oRootLDAP
Dim oContainer

' Holding variables for information import from CSV file
Dim sLogon
Dim sFirstName
Dim sLastName
Dim sDisplayName
Dim sPassword
Dim nPwdLastSet
Dim nUserAccountControl ' Used to enable the account
Dim sDomain

' Modify this to match your company's AD domain
sDomain="mydomain.com"

' Input file location
sCSVFileLocation = "C:\Scripts\" 'KEEP TRAILING SLASH!

' Full path to input file
sCSVFile = sCSVFileLocation&"Book2.csv"

' Commands used to open the CSV file and select all of the records
set oConnection = createobject("adodb.connection")
set oRecordSet = createobject("adodb.recordset")
oConnection.open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & sCSVFileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited"""
oRecordSet.open "SELECT * FROM " & sCSVFile ,oConnection

' Create a connection to the Active Directory Users container.
Set oRootLDAP = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
Set oContainer = GetObject("LDAP://cn=Users," & _
oRootLDAP.Get("defaultNamingContext"))

' Allows processing to continue even if an error occurs (i.e. dup user)
' We put this below the CSV and AD information since processing can
' continue with a single bad record, but not if there is a problem with
' the CSV file or AD connection
on error resume next

do until oRecordSet.EOF ' Reads the values (cells) in the sInputFile file.

' --------- Start creating user account
' Read variable information from the CSV file
' and build everything needed to create the account
sLogon = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(0).value
sFirstName = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(1).value
sLastName = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(2).value
sDisplayName = sLastName&", "&sFirstName
sPassword = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(3).value

' Build the User account
Set oNewUser = oContainer.Create("User","cn="&sFirstName&" "&SLastName)

oNewUser.put "sAMAccountName",lcase(sLogon)
oNewUser.put "givenName",sFirstName
oNewUser.put "sn",sLastName
oNewUser.put "UserPrincipalName",lcase(SLogon)&"@"&sDomain
oNewUser.put "DisplayName",sDisplayName
oNewUser.put "name",lcase(sLogon)

' Write this information into Active Directory so we can
' modify the password and enable the user account
oNewUser.SetInfo

' Change the users password
oNewUser.SetPassword sPassword
oNewUser.Put "pwdLastSet", 0

' Enable the user account
oNewUser.Put "userAccountControl", 512
oNewUser.SetInfo

' Used only for debugging
'if err.number = -2147019886 then
' msgbox "User logon " & sLogon & "already exists"
'End If

' --------- End of user account creation
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from some further google searching.
At the end I needed a:
oRecordSet.MoveNext
loop

And it worked then.